# Code faster with swap as function rather than within the algorithm itself

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

So I've been testing the running time of sorting algorithms in C, and I keep making slight modifications to the code seeing how it will affect the speed and such, one such modification was making swapping in bubble sort within the sorting algorithm rather than being a separate function call, I expected it to be faster that way since function calls open up there own stack frames, but it turned out to be almost twice as slower, and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
void Swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
void BubbleSort(int data[], int size)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    bool is_sorted = false;
    for (i = 0; i < (size - 1) && !is_sorted; i++)
    {
        is_sorted = true;
        for (j = size - 1; j > i; j--)
            if (data[j] < data[j - 1])
            {
                //used to be swap(data[j],data[j-1];
                temp = data[j];
                data[j] = data[j - 1];
                data[j-1] = temp;
                is_sorted = false;
            }
    }
}
```

- Edit to answer comments, yes I did run with compiler optimizations on release, If you want to see how I got the running time here is the full code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7363330

Comment: Did you compile *with* optimization (e.g. `-O3`)?

Comment: how did you test the running time?

Comment: It may be naive and I surely don't have the answer for sure but calling the Swap, you access data and j only twice. In the method where you don't call Swap, you access data and j 4 times (and moreover you compute j - 1 twice). To me, it makes more computation but I repeat, it may be naive ;)

Comment: @user2968505 which compiler are you using ?

Comment: @user2968505 And which compiler flags?

Comment: @user2968505 What type of processor do you have?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the compiler optimises the `temp` variable away when it's in a function and the swap is recognised for what it is. But without the function the scope of the `temp` variable extends outside the block that it is used in, so without sufficient levels of optimisation the compiler might always store the last “temporary” value in it.

Try moving the declaration of `temp` from outside the loop to where you are using it, i.e., `int temp = data[j]`.

Anyhow, this is just a guess; look at the produced assembly to verify.

Comment: I've actually tested that before, by doing as you said and testing the running time but it gave pretty much the same running time.

Comment: Could also be that the compiler recalculates the address of `data[index]` (so in general 4 extra additions and 2 subtractions). Best way is to look at the assembly of course.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected it to be faster that way since function calls open up
>   there own stack frames

It is perfectly reasonable to expect `Swap` to be inlined. In that case, the compiler does basically the same thing as you did manually and there will be no difference between the two versions.

And indeed, I have checked the code you posted here at SO both with clang 3.4 (trunk) and gcc 4.7.2, with optimization level `-O3` and **there is absolutely no difference between the two versions of your swap** (`Swap` function vs. manually inlined swap).

Here is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

void Swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

void BubbleSort(int data[], int size)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    bool is_sorted = false;
    for (i = 0; i < (size - 1) && !is_sorted; i++)
    {
        is_sorted = true;
        for (j = size - 1; j > i; j--)

            if (data[j] < data[j - 1])
            {
                Swap(data[j],data[j-1]);
                //temp = data[j];
                //data[j] = data[j - 1];
                //data[j-1] = temp;
                is_sorted = false;
            }
    }
}

int main() {

    const int SIZE = 30000;

    std::vector<int> v(SIZE);

    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937(5489u));

    using namespace boost::chrono;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    BubbleSort(v.data(), v.size());

    auto finish = high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::printf("%ld  ms\n", duration_cast<milliseconds>(finish-start).count());
}
```

I compiled with `(clan)g++ -O3 -std=c++11 sort.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_chrono -lrt`.

So, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Due to the use of `__int64 `, I'm guessing the OP compiles it with MSVC, which may behave differently.

Comment: @nos Yes, that's possible. However, it is reasonable to expect the same performance and both clang and gcc generate code where there is no difference. Maybe the OP is not using the appropriate compiler flags.

Comment: @nos Yeah i am using Microsoft Visual studio 2013 which uses the MSVC compiler.

Comment: @Ali i am pretty much an amateur, i don't even know what compiler flags are.

Comment: @user2968505 Then my guess is that you have different running times because your compiler flags are not set properly. If you set them properly, you won't see any difference in the running times. Unfortunately I don't have MSVC or Windows, so I cannot help you with that... :(